# Why is ''' used for multiline strings in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, multilinestring, delphi-12-athens

The Delphi programming language recently introduced multiline strings with the release of Delphi 12, but I would like to know why the following way was used for multiline strings instead of the way other languages do it?

I much prefer the way JavaScript does it using `` ` `` for multiline strings. This seems much better, so why did Delphi decide to use `'''` over something like `` ` ``?

In JavaScript, it is:

```
var html = `
  <div>
    <span>Some HTML here</span>
  </div>
`;
```

One simple `` ` `` seems much better. What's the reason for `'''`?

Comment: FYI, asking questions about WHY something is done a particular way is usually off-topic for StackOverflow, unless someone who was actually involved in (or knows the details of) the decision-making process can chime in.

Comment: Also, three apostrophes seem much better than a backtick. ;-)  Easier to enter, easier to read. (Well, that's my true opinion.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new syntax takes inspiration<sup>*</sup> from C#'s [raw string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/raw-string-literal), which uses (but is not limited to) `"""`.

<sup>* New features introduced in Delphi over the last decade or so take a lot of inspiration from C#.</sup>

For what's it worth, Embarcadero did consider using backticks/delimiters like you are suggesting, amongst other approaches.  What we have now is what they finally settled on.